# CSSO Gulp and WordPress Comments

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, gulp, csso

I am using Gulp CSSO to tidy up my CSS in WordPress but it deletes my comments, more specifically it deletes the theme meta data. Is there any way to get around this? Perhaps insert the theme meta data after I have run CSSO?

Answer (score 1):

The [csso](http://bem.info/tools/optimizers/csso/description/) documentation page says that it will remove the comments,because they do not affect rendering, but:

> If you want to save the comment, CSSO can do it with only one first comment in case it starts with **!**.

So I don't think you can preserve a comment with the wordpress metadata format.

Why don't you apply gulp-csso first and then add the metadata as a prefix using **gulp-header**?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you use the `!` at the beginning of a single comment declaration such as:

```
/*!

...Your Theme declaration here...

*/
```

WordPress will properly detect the declaration, and CSSO will preserve the comment.